# TYPO3 DAM - Backend fileupload doesn't work

Tags: typo3

i am using DAM for my lokal TYPO3 4.7.7.
I want to upload a file in the TYPO3 Backend (File -> Filelist), but it doesn't work! 
When i press the upload button nothing happens....

Comment: Apparently some bug... maybe wrong config, use inspection tool to see JS errors and search it in the net

Comment: Can i also check this with firebug? If so, how?

Comment: Yes Firebug is what I mean by inspection tool, check in the network TAB what response is incoming when you trying to upload and/or, check console for error logs

Comment: When i click at the button, nothing happens. The error logs are empty. Same in the network tab. After clearing the console and click at the button nothing response.... this is strange

Comment: hm try another browser...

Comment: i try this now on IE and the backend upload on this browser is possible!!! :P So there are some issues with firefox